# Postgres regex issue

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to find all records stored in postgres, which matching following regexp:

```
^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.phone ~ '^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$'
```

But this one falls with error:

> invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Why won't Postgres work with this regex?

Using the same one in plain Ruby works just fine.

**UPDATE**

Problem is only with WHERE. When i try to:

```
SELECT '+79637434199' ~ '^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)[\d\- ]{7,10}'
```

Postgres returns true. But when i try:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.phone ~ '^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)[\d\- ]{7,10}'
```

Result: **"invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid"**.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this? There have been some fixes in regular expression handling recently, so minor release number may be significant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to escape `-` inside a character class when you put it at the first or last position, because it cannot be misread as range that way:

`[\- ]` → `[- ]`
`[\d\- ]` → `[\d -]`

The way you have it the upper bound `10` at the end is futile.
Add `$` at the end to disallow trailing characters.
Or `\D` to disallow trailing *digits* (but require a non-digit).
Or `($|\D)` to either end the string there or have a non-digit follow.

Put together:

```
SELECT '+79637434199' ~ '^(8|\+7)[ -]?(\(?\d{3}\)?[ -]?)[\d -]{7,10}($|\D)'
```

Otherwise your expression is just fine and it works for me on PostgreSQL 9.1.4. It should not make any difference whatsoever whether you use it in a `WHERE` clause or in a `SELECT` list - unless you are running into a bug with some old version (like @kgrittn commented).

---

If I prepend the string literal with `E`, I can provoke the error message that you get. This *cannot* explain your problem, because you stated that the expression works fine as `SELECT` item.

But, as Sherlock Holmes is quoted, "when you have excluded the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

Maybe you ran one test with [`standard_conforming_strings = on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) and the other one with `standard_conforming_strings = off` - this was the default interpretation of string literals in older versions before 9.1. Maybe with two different clients (that have a different setting as to that).

Read more in the chapter [String Constants with C-style Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in the manual.