# Postgres invalid regular expression: invalid character range

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm using the following line in a postgres function:

`regexp_replace(input, '[^a-z0-9\-_]+', sep, 'gi');`

But I'm getting `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid character range` when I try to use it. The regex works fine in Ruby, is there a reason it'd be different in postgres?

Comment: I don't know but if I were you I will try to put the hyphen at the end of the character class or  I will try to escape it twice.

Comment: I run that with no error. Maybe provide the rest of your code?

Comment: This post may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069639/postgres-regex-issue

Comment: Postgres 9.5: `select regexp_replace('a_b%d-e', '[^a-z0-9\-_]+', '|', 'gi')` is ok and yields `a_b|d-e`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some regexp parsers will work with a dash (-) in the middle, if after a range like you have it, but others won't.  I suspect the `postgres` regexp parser is in the later class.  The canonical way to have the dash in a regexp is to start with it, i.e. change the regexp to `'[^-a-z0-9_]+'` which might get it past the parser.  Some regexp parsers, however, can be really fussy and not accept that, either.

I don't have a `postgres` to test with, but I expect they'll accept the regexp above and deal correctly.  Otherwise you have to find the regexp portion of their manual and understand what it says about this.

Comment: Is the dash `-` really all that different than any other non-alphanum literal ? Perhaps it doesn't accept escapes at all. In reality `[^a-z0-9-_]` contains a valid dash literal when outside the context of a range operator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

using

\-

instead of only

-

worked to me

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to move the dash (-) to the end of the list

replaced `[A-Za-z0-9-_.+=]` with `[A-Za-z0-9_.+=-]` seems to work

Answer (score 0):

[^[:digit:]\-.]

The above code will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).